# Output redirection on Windows using the C language

Tags: c, output-redirect

How do you redirect output in Windows using C?

I tried doing "./echo > myfile.txt", but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Even on Unix, `./echo` would run the `echo` command in the **current** directory. (On Windows `.\programname` would be more appropriate but I think either slash works. Maybe.) To run the global one from the path, just use `echo > ...`.

Comment: Also this isn't using C at all. Do you mean from the command prompt? Because in C doing this involves quite a bit more code.

Comment: this is not the C language, more like Batch/Cmd commands

Comment: @millimoose Maybe "echo" is his own program and not the `echo` utility. Else I fail to see where C would come in at all..

Comment: @Thomas It might be, but given the very terse question and the OP being a new user, I'm leaning with the OP being confused about "the basics" rather than merely not providing sufficient context. Either way speculating isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: @user2714453: So. Is `echo` your own program or are you trying to invoke the standard `echo` command on Windows? Where does C come into this? Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

`echo.exe > myfile.txt`

and

`echo.exe >> myfile.txt` to append to file

considering `echo.exe` is your executable

Comment: And the normal `echo` command with no arguments will simply add a newline to the end of the file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah, I think OP has `echo.exe`

Comment: Nitpick: `echo` is hardly a MS-DOS command unless the OP is using Windows 98. All consumer versions of Windows since XP are based on the NT kernel which doesn't descend from MS-DOS, it merely reimplements some of its shell environment in `cmd.exe`. (Wiki tells me that for example the `deltree` command was removed and replaced with a flag for `rd`.) `COMMAND.COM` doesn't exist either, it's just an alias for `cmd.exe` which is also a different beast altogether.

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion. Echo is the name of my program. It merely copies what user inputs thus the name "echo". What i wanted was to output my text in another file but everytime I open it, its empty

Answer (score 1):

Great Info here:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php

Short Extract:

### Redirection

---

`command > file`                  | Write standard output of command to file
`command 1> file`                 | Write standard output of command to file (same as previous)
`command 2> file`                 | Write standard error of command to file (OS/2 and NT)
`command > file 2>&1`             | Write both standard output and standard error of command to file (OS/2 and NT)
`command >> file`                 | Append standard output of command to file
`command 1>> file`                | Append standard output of command to file (same as previous)
`command 2>> file`                | Append standard error of command to file (OS/2 and NT)
`command >> file 2>&1`            | Append both standard output and standard error of command to file (OS/2 and NT)
`commandA | commandB`        | Redirect standard output of commandA to standard input of commandB
`commandA 2>&1 | commandB`  | Redirect standard output and standard error of commandA to standard input of commandB (OS/2 and NT)
`command < file`                    | command gets standard input from file
`command 2>&1`                  | command's standard error is redirected to standard output (OS/2 and NT)
`command 1>&2`                  | command's standard output is redirected to standard error (OS/2 and NT)

---

Ps. No need for slashes...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

It is the wrong slash for a Windows command shell. The OP used `/`, and they should have used `\`.

Use `.\echo > myfile.txt`